# “Failed to fetch updates” in App Center while using Elementary OS Loki

Tags: updates, software-installation, appcenter, repositories

Every time I use either the; Terminal and the `sudo apt-get update` command or just open the App Center,(auto updates every time its opened) i get a pop up saying `Failed to Fetch Updates`

I cant seem to find the answer anywhere online. Can someone please help!

When I get the pop up and after clicking details i get the following information --

```
W: The repository 'cdrom://elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki - Stable amd64 (20180214) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: cdrom://elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki - Stable amd64 (20180214) xenial/contrib amd64 Packages is not (yet) available (Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The repository 'cdrom://elementary OS 0.4 \_Loki\_ - Stable amd64 (20160921) xenial Release' does not have a Release file"](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/the-repository-cdrom-elementary-os-0-4-loki-stable-amd64-20160921-xeni)

Comment: While searching for my issue, this one solved it for me: [**Update with terminal instead of AppCenter**](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7490/14684)

Answer (score 1):

After Researching all day i finally found the answer. I hope this helps someone..

First open **"Software & Updates"** and click on the **"Other Software"** tab for my issue, The box at the top named **"cdrom:[elementary OS 0.4.1 *Loki*-Stable amd64 (201880214)]/xenial"** was "checked" or selected and it shouldn't have been. i unchecked and it was fixed.

Comment: Awesome, you should be able to mark this as the "accepted answer" by clicking the icon to the left. I believe this will be available 24~48 hours after answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not finding "Software and Updates" anywhere on my Loki system, but you can use Settings | Repositories" in Synaptic or you can just edit the repo list manually

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

Sry for wrong english if any..

By clicking at applications tab..
 there is a pop up menu/window..

on which you can search for software and updates..

by clicking at software and update just go for other software (scnd option from the left at the row)

Uncheck the first option i.e. cdrom:[elementary OS 0.4.1........

That's it..